# Make *ngFor work for individual mouseover and mouseout events

Tags: angular

Here's my Angular code:

```
<div *ngFor="let follow of followers;">
  <div>{{follow.name}}</div>
  <div>
    <button (mouseover)="myFollow=true" (mouseout)="myFollow=false" (click)="follow(id)">
      <span [hidden]="myFollow">Following</span>
      <span [hidden]="!myFollow">Follow</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the output:

```
Joe1 Following
Joe2 Following
Joe3 Following
Joe4 Following
```

When I mouse-over the first row, all the rows change to:

```
Joe1 Follow
Joe2 Follow
Joe3 Follow
Joe4 Follow
```

It should change only the first row like this:

```
Joe1 Follow
Joe2 Following
Joe3 Following
Joe4 Following
```

How do I make the `(mouseover)` and `(mouseout)` to work for individual rows?

This is my corresponding .ts file

```
public followers = [] as [{follow_data?: any}];
export class FollowingComponent OnInit {
  myFollow: boolean;
  constructor() {
    this.myFollow = false;
  }
```

Here's how the JSON looks like:

```
"followers": [
    {
        "follow_data": {
            "name": "joe1",
            "id": "863cf135-8105-0d0df0e1c101"
    },
    {
        "follow_data": {
            "name": "joe2",
            "id": "863cf135-8105-0d0df0e1c102"
    },
    {
        "follow_data": {
            "name": "joe3",
            "id": "863cf135-8105-0d0df0e1c103"
    },
    {
        "follow_data": {
            "name": "joe4",
            "id": "863cf135-8105-0d0df0e1c104"
    },
]
```

Comment: is follow an object or a boolean? i have a feeling you want `follow.follow=true;` and `follow.follow=false;`

Comment: boolean and not an object. edited the question.

Comment: is `myFollow` a property of the `follow` object? or is it a variable in the class?

Comment: No. It was created just for the mouse hover events.

Comment: so where is it? you cant have a variable in html without anything in the typescript file, edit your `followers` array class/interface to have a follow property in it

Comment: Updated the .ts file. This is the entire code.

Comment: you cant do that, the `myFollow` will change all of them at once, you need to change the `followers` array class/interface to have a follow property in it

Comment: How?! That's what I'm asking. It is changing all of them at once.

Comment: i have told you twice now but you seem to be ignoring the advice i am giving you, can you post your class/interface definition for the `followers` array?

Comment: Followers array comes from the JSON file. That array has nothing to do with the mouseover/mouseout event.

Comment: well without changing the array, or showing us the structure of said json, we cant provide you with a solution

Comment: Added the sample JSON data.

Comment: You can ignore the (click) function. All I'm trying to do here is to change "following " to "follow" on mouseover and "follow" to "following" on mouseout.

Comment: inside each `follow_data`, add an `isFollowing` boolean, then in your html code, use `<div>{{follow.follow_data.name}}</div>` and also `(mouseover)="follow.follow_data.isFollowing=true" (mouseout)="follow.follow_data.isFollowing=false"`

Comment: Could you post this as an answer? Also, I can't change the JSON file. It's from a third party backend.

Comment: if its a third party backend, you will have trouble doing this as you need to have a different json structure

Comment: Just for a mouseover-mouseout?!! Anyways, I'll go for the CSS method then.

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, because you need some kind of variable per item/object that you can use and you dont have one currently

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the follow var, set a property of the follow (ex. follow.following = true)

Answer (score -1):

Add a property to your model in typescript, `following: boolean`, and toggle it on mouseover/mouseout

```
<button (mouseover)="follow.following = true" (mouseout)="follow.following = false" (click)="follow(id)">
      <span [hidden]="follow.following">Following</span>
      <span [hidden]="!follow.following">Follow</span>
    </button>
```